# How to get the entire list of operators?

Tags: python, interface

I want to create a list with everything the spacebar operator search can produce. Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes,
See: `Help -> Operator Cheat Sheet`

This operator is written in Python, See : `startup/bl_operators/wm.py` for the source is you like to get this data for your own use in Python.

The result can be viewed in the text editor:

[image]

Comment: Only 1469? Cool, now I can keep track of new operators.

Comment: The number is not so important it depends on compile options and which addons you have enabled.