# Is there a list for all available python functions?

Tags: python

I know that a list of math functions can be found [on this site](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/contents.html#standalone-modules)

But how about functions such as

- `obj.data.materials.clear()`
- `obj.data.materials.append()`
- `len(obj.data.polygons)`
- `.normal` or
- `.length` ?

I have always wondered whether there was an overview or list or whatnot for these functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These functions (or rather methods, properties and attributes) you are asking for are blender-specific, thus part of the **Blender Python API** (a.k.a. bpy) - just to clear it up. For standard python module features, please refer to the [official python docs](http://docs.python.org/3/).

`.polygons`, `.length` etc. are properties of certain Blender type instances (objects). To find out what they do and which features are available, you need to check out the [bpy API docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/) for a **particular type** (class).

There is a page in the docs about how to use the docs:
[Blender/Python API Reference Usage: examples of how to use the API reference docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/info_api_reference.html)

> ### Example
>
> `.polygons` is a property of the type [bpy.types.Mesh](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=polygons#bpy.types.Mesh.polygons).
>
> It is a type on its own, [MeshPolygons](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.MeshPolygons.html#bpy.types.MeshPolygons), > which has an `.active` property and an `add()` method.
>
> If you use the slice notation on `.polygons`, you will get elements returned of a `bpy_prop_collection`. The element type is [MeshPolygon](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html#bpy.types.MeshPolygon). A MeshPolygon has i.e. a `.normal` property in turn.

As you can see, the methods and properties are not found in a single place. The most valuable information is hidden in the `bpy.types` section of the docs. You can use the online search, or use Blender's built-in Python Console with auto-complete to figure out what is where. You can also find out the type and search for it in the API docs by adding `bl_rna.identifier` to an object:

```
>>> bpy.context.object.data.bl_rna.identifier
'Mesh'

>>> bpy.context.object.data.polygons.bl_rna.identifier
'MeshPolygons'

>>> bpy.context.object.data.polygons[0].bl_rna.identifier
'MeshPolygon'
```

Prepend `bpy.types.` and you have your type to lookup in the docs!

Answer (score 9):

An API navigator can be enabled under *File > User Preferences > Addons*, Supported Level: *Development*, search for *API navigator*.

Change a window to the text editor and in the properties panel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) there will now be a foldable menu called *API Navigator*.

Hope it helps =)

[image]

Also... if you right click any UI element and click *Edit Source*, the code will be displayed in this editor (unless it's from C code, you'll see a message in this case)

Comment: and of coarse if you dont understand the code you see there, codeman has pointed to the official docs, which can be cross-referenced with the actual source to obtain a more complete understanding of whats going on... i honestly never use the API nav, mostly because i get distracted from actually doing what i mean to do and end up just browsing the api.... for hours on end... which would be fine if i was trying to learn python... but i want to model, not code... lol

Answer (score 3):

While you can easily get a [list of operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/how-to-get-the-entire-list-of-operators) I don't think anyone has done the same for all of blender. It would probably be too large anyway.

There is help available directly from python, you can use blender's Python console to access it. Starting with the autocomplete feature, typing in `obj.data.materials.` and pressing the Autocomplete button ( or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) will list all items available, even having entered `D.objects['` autocomplete will list available object names.

The next option is listing all class attributes, which is methods and variables, so entering `dir(C.active_object.data.materials)` into the console gives you -

```
['__bool__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__doc__',
'__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__module__', '__setattr__',
'__setitem__', '__slots__', 'append', 'bl_rna', 'clear', 'find', 'foreach_get',
'foreach_set', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'rna_type', 'values']
```

Names surrounded by double underline are 'builtin' implementations as defined by python - eg `__len__` is the function called when you use `len(C.active_object.data.materials)`

Currently of limited use (the scrollback length in the console is too small) is the help function. eg `help(C.active_object.data.materials)` will output -

```
Help on bpy_prop_collection object:

class bpy_prop_collection(bpy_prop)
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      bpy_prop_collection
 |      bpy_prop
 |      object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __bool__(...)
 |      x.__bool__() <==> x != 0
 |  
 |  __contains__(...)
 |      x.__contains__(y) <==> y in x
 |  
 |  __delattr__(...)
 |      x.__delattr__('name') <==> del x.name
 |  
<snip>
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from bpy_prop:
 |  
 |  __dir__(...)
 |  
 |  __eq__(...)
 |      x.__eq__(y) <==> x==y
 |  
 |  __ge__(...)
 |      x.__ge__(y) <==> x>=y
<snip>
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from bpy_prop:
 |  
 |  data
 |      The data this property is using, *type* :class:`bpy.types.bpy_struct`
 |  
 |  id_data
 |      The :class:`bpy.types.ID` object this datablock is from or None, (not available for all data types)
 |  
 |  rna_type
 |      The property type for introspection
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes inherited from bpy_prop:
 |  
 |  __new__ = <built-in method __new__ of type object>
 |      T.__new__(S, ...) -> a new object with type S, a subtype of T
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Operator Sheat Sheet under Help in Blender.

When you open the Text Editor there is a list with all install operator

Comment: Thanks for your answer mkb, but that's what @sambler already said.

Answer (score 0):

For every python object there are two functions that everybody should know about - `dir` and `help` they do what they say on the box so for anything you can type in the console `dir(theobject)` to get a list of methods and `help(theobject.somemethod)` to get the help information.  These are python builtin functions that should work everywhere.

Note that any members that start with one or more underscores (_) are **private** and should not be relied on to be available or the same in future or later versions.

Comment: I was going to write this answer before I saw it here.  I guess people wanted a more user-friendly interlace