# Is there a list for Keyframe data_paths in Blender?

Tags: python, animation, keyframes

I found some really useful code for keyframe animations. 
But i need a specific property (in this case for the Cycles camera visibility) 
and i only found "location", "gravity" or "value". 
Is there some kind of List of all the keyframe data_paths?
Or a option to "see" the names of the animationpaths ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a list for all available python functions?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8067/is-there-a-list-for-all-available-python-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CoDEmanX describes below, your best bet is to go to the [API Documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_5/) and search for `bpy.types.` plus the type and property (for example, search for `bpy.types.Object.hide`). There you can find [how to `hide`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=bpy.types.object.hide#bpy.types.Object.hide).

You can also see [here how to figure out data paths](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/info_api_reference.html).

Comment: The data paths in python tooltips are rarely useful, better go to the [API Docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/250PythonDoc/) and search for `bpy.types.` plus the type and property (e.g. `bpy.types.Object.hide`). It will find: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=bpy.types.object.hide#bpy.types.Object.hide See here how to figure out data paths: [Blender/Python API Reference Usage: examples of how to use the API reference docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/info_api_reference.html)

Comment: The datapaths in tooltips have been improved, there are fewer ellipses now.

Answer (score 8):

You can right click the property in the user interface and choose `Copy Data Path`

You can also key it manually and explore the object's animation data with the outliner using the data block option.

[image: outliner]

or view it in the graph editor

[image: graph editor]

You might try to create a list yourself:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
txt = bpy.data.texts.new("list")
for prop in obj.bl_rna.properties:
    if prop.is_animatable and not prop.is_readonly:
        txt.write(prop.identifier + '\n')
    elif prop.type == "POINTER":
        txt.write("---Pointer--- \n" + prop.identifier + '\n')
        for sub in prop.fixed_type.bl_rna.properties:
            if sub.is_animatable and not sub.is_readonly:
                txt.write(sub.identifier + '\n')
        txt.write("------------- \n")
```

It is possible to explore the properties with the outliner:

[image: rna_properties]

Comment: this should be the validated answer