# how to find the data_path for scripted keyframes

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I would like to script keyframes for bevel modifier width (and many more later). Here is what I have so far. I've commented out the last line which doesn't work. When I type `help(ao.keyframe_insert)`, I get `:arg data_path: path to the property to key, analogous to the fcurve's data path.` but that doesn't help me since I haven't use fcurves yet.

The first half of my question is "*how to key the bevel width as I am trying in the example script?*"

...and the second half is "*where could I have looked this up?*" or "*how can I know in general what do write in `keyframe_insert(data_path=""` without asking a new question each time I want to key something?*"

Thanks for your understanding!

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

frame_a, frame_b = 25, 35
sigma_a, sigma_b = 7, 10
n_frames = 60

if 1 == 1:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=1, location=(0.0, 0.0, 2.0))
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BEVEL')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].width = 0.3
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].segments = 3

ao = bpy.context.active_object

bpy.context.scene.frame_end = n_frames

for i_frame in range(n_frames):
    a = np.exp(-(i_frame - frame_a)**2 / (2.*sigma_a**2))
    s = 1.0 + 0.3 * a
    bw = 1.0 * a
    ao.modifiers["Bevel"].width = bw
    ao.scale = (s, s, s)
    ao.keyframe_insert(data_path="scale", frame = i_frame + 1, index=-1)
    #ao.keyframe_insert(data_path="modifiers['Bevel'].width", frame = i_frame + 1, index=-1)
```

Comment: just switch the double quotes and the single quotes in the last line `'modifiers["Bevel"].width'`

Comment: Wow! @Chebhou that's just what I needed - thanks!  I'm wondering now should I just delete the question (it's really a non-question almost).

Comment: I'll try @zeffii. That's a good answer to link to. But I don't know what an "outliner" is.

Comment: Aha! got it. But I don't see how one could find `'modifiers["Bevel"].width'` by looking at the outliner.

Comment: @uhoh you can find it from the UI not the outliner exactly

Comment: OK up there at the top, the scrolling python narrative, right next to the left-handed smoke shifter.

Comment: possible duplicate :(  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/is-there-a-list-for-keyframe-data-paths-in-blender/9368#9368

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the data_path of a UI element (property, icon..), rightclick it and select "Copy Data Path"

[image]

Wrapping the resulting data_path with double quotes is a legal python string representation (eg: `"modifiers['Bevel'].width"`), and arguably should be allowed. But the parser of properties favours `'modifiers["Bevel"].width'`, presumably to keep the string parsing to a  minimal implementation.

---

The above will be able to compute most kinds of `data_path`, but if it fails you can

- make a keyframe for the property
- go to the Outliner (set to view Datablocks)
- navigate to Actions -> (Object/Scenename)+Action -> F-Curve
- See Data Path. (this is what the initial

  > path to the property to key, analogous to the fcurve's data path

  refers to.)

Comment: I see many good things I didn't know where there when I right click things like buttons, objects, or even sub-items in the outliner. But I never see "Copy data_path" I'm using 2.74 but do I need to turn something on?

Comment: No, it's me. I just failed to click on things that were actually data. The image is extremely helpful!