# What's the data_path of lamp energy? BUG?

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I'm trying to insert a keyframe via python to animate energy lamp but i get this TypeError:

```
o.keyframe_insert(data_path='energy', frame=5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "energy" not found
```

The data_path "energy" should be correct, as explained here [how to find the data_path for scripted keyframes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34590/how-to-find-the-data-path-for-scripted-keyframes) just rightclick the Energy property and select "Copy Data Path".

Distance property don't works too.

I tried this on several Blender version: 2.71, 2.74, 2.76b, 2.77

More:
I added manually the energy lamp animation and by checking this value:

```
bpy.context.object.data.animation_data.action.fcurves[0].data_path
```

i get still the same value 'energy'

It's a bug or i'm doing it wrong? There is some workaround?

**SOLVED**

I was confused by the fact that the property color was animatable directly from the lamp object otherwise energy and distance can be animated by lamp.data

The correct code

```
o.data.keyframe_insert(data_path='energy', frame=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the three choices my bet is that you're doing it wrong in that your o object is the lamp object, not the data part, or some other non LAMP data object.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
#o = bpy.data.objects.get("Lamp") # assumes you have an ob named Lamp
#o.data = bpy.data.lamps.get("Lamp")
o = context.active_object
if o:
    #o.energy 
    print("%s (%s)" % (o.name, o.type), getattr(o, "energy", "Has NO energy property"))
    o = o.data
    #o.data.energy
    if o:
        print("%s (%s)" % (o.name, o.type), getattr(o, "energy",  "Has NO energy property"))
```

If you grab a datapath from the DATA Properties panel, eg mesh panel for mesh objects, the datapath will be resolvable on the data part. 
`context.active_object.data`  (except for empties, whose data part is None)